# On the programmatic creation of non-English 'syngraphs' for the purpose of lexicon study

Tags: language-acquisition, translation, synonymy, wordnet

I am a native English speaker. I have recently come to the conclusion that the main obstacle in my learning of foreign languages is always the study of the lexicon, which is vast and largely 'arbitrary', 'accidental', or 'unnatural' at least in comparison with the largely rule-based nature of the grammar etc. My goal (like any other idealist learner's) is to 'rapidly' learn a language, and so for me it will be necessary to innovate a bit regarding the study of vocabulary.

I have had some success with more 'traditional' means of studying vocabulary, including direct means such as listing vocabulary in a 'gloss' (in a variety of contexts, eg whether during study of a text, or a small notebook carried to record new words) and indirect means like the study/reading of a text itself (more generally, words in context).

I am convinced that, for me, it would be very effective to be able to represent lexical semantic relations (that is, between individual, isolated words, phrases, or even idioms, whatever the 'semantic unit' happens to be) in a 'geometric' or 'visual' fashion, so as to exploit the capacity of the mind to learn in this fashion. This isn't a new technique of course since the capacity to learn visually has always been exploited in a variety of contexts.

To give an example for this context, the 'syngraph' mentioned in the title would be a 'graph', by which I mean a collection of isolated points and arrows between them, where the points are the indivudal words and the arrows perhaps indicate a synonym relationship. Or any other number of possible variations. 
But more generally, the key for me would be the relationships encoded by how near the given words are to each other, and most importantly, the fact that the group of words somehow lies within a given 'class' of words, whether that class is a category like 'Words you use at the supermarket', or 'Japanese Kanji which use this particular radical', or something as specific as 'Words/phrases expressing surprise', etc. The depiction isn't necessarily restricted to arrows etc

In any case, the main difficulty is that creating these representations is time-consuming, especially for someone whose time is scarce. Leaving the general case aside, I would therefore be interested in a way to programmatically generate 'synonym graph' depictions as outlined above, for a foreign language, which could then be tweaked for specific cases.

If I were to do this from scratch, I would basically take subgraphs from WordNet (whether for synonym relationship or otherwise, I don't remember all the relations), then 'lift' the graph into an item-wise translation automatically using something like Google Translate (though this would not be the most reliable way to do it, especially for some more difficult languages), then pipe it through some graph-creation software like Sigma.js. (Ideally, we would have programmatic access to Google's synonym graph that is made available on the Translator web interface, but I don't think this will happen).

Has anyone ever done something like this and want to share their methods, advice, or even code? Are there existing tools that do this, or something like it? There may be important variations on the method I described that I have left out, I have not thought about it too extensively and I have not proofread the above. I am particularly interested in the following languages:

French
Japanese
Korean
Russian
Portuguese

Comment: So you're after something like [Kirrkirr](http://nlp.stanford.edu/kirrkirr/)?

Comment: @A__A__0 I suppose it depends on your precise learning goals, but my sincere advice as a polyglot is that this is the wrong approach for learning foreign languages.  (I say this although my work is based on placing translated words and phrases on a variety of dimensions.)